# Change '0777' string to 0777 octal LITERALLY

Tags: php, permissions, chmod, octal

My code is like

```
$perm = "0777"; //this is fetched from the database
chmod("myFolder/", $perm);
```

but the value of $perm is not in octal, how can I change the data type of the variable to octal? even an alternative method will do

Answer (score 8):

As it was mentioned, there is no octal number type. And chmod function receive the second param as integer number. Implicit conversion of `$perm` does not assume that number is octal. So, you need convert your "octal string" to integer by using appropriate function.

Just use [octdec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.octdec.php) function

```
$perm = "0777"; //this is fetch from the database
chmod("myFolder/", octdec($perm));
```

Or [intval](http://php.net/intval)

```
chmod("myFolder/", intval($perm, 8));
```

P.S.

```
var_dump('0644' == 0644);             // bool(false)
var_dump(intval('0644') == 0644);     // bool(false)
var_dump(decoct('0644') == 0644);     // bool(false)

var_dump(octdec('0644') == 0644);     // bool(true)
var_dump(intval('0644', 8) == 0644);  // bool(true)
```

Comment: To be clear, there is an octal integer format in PHP, [per the manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php) *"Integers can be specified in decimal (base 10), hexadecimal (base 16), octal (base 8) or binary (base 2) notation*" -- indicated by a leading zero. In addition, please see the [manual on `chmod`](https://www.php.net/chmod): `chmod("/somedir/somefile", 0755);  // octal; correct value of mode`. In today's type-strict environment, your first `chmod` example would throw a type error, because `octdec` returns a string, not an integer.

Comment: @MarkusAO, sure there is many different notations to write number in code. But there no octal number type, just integer. Also octdec returns int....

Comment: Sorry, meant to make a note on [`decoct()`](https://www.php.net/decoct) returning a string. In related notes, it seems that PHP doesn't remember what base notation the integer was defined in, as in, an integer variable always returns a decimal integer by default.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing seemed to work for me so i just created a very stupid solution and I'm just gonna post it here.

```
function permtooct($permissions) {      

    $mode = 0; 
    if ($permissions[0] == '1') $mode += 01000; 
    if ($permissions[0] == '2') $mode += 02000; 
    if ($permissions[0] == '3') $mode += 03000; 
    if ($permissions[0] == '4') $mode += 04000; 
    if ($permissions[0] == '5') $mode += 05000; 
    if ($permissions[0] == '6') $mode += 06000; 
    if ($permissions[0] == '7') $mode += 07000; 

    if ($permissions[1] == '1') $mode += 0100; 
    if ($permissions[1] == '2') $mode += 0200; 
    if ($permissions[1] == '3') $mode += 0300; 
    if ($permissions[1] == '4') $mode += 0400; 
    if ($permissions[1] == '5') $mode += 0500; 
    if ($permissions[1] == '6') $mode += 0600; 
    if ($permissions[1] == '7') $mode += 0700; 

    if ($permissions[2] == '1') $mode += 010; 
    if ($permissions[2] == '2') $mode += 020; 
    if ($permissions[2] == '3') $mode += 030; 
    if ($permissions[2] == '4') $mode += 040; 
    if ($permissions[2] == '5') $mode += 050; 
    if ($permissions[2] == '6') $mode += 060; 
    if ($permissions[2] == '7') $mode += 070; 

    if ($permissions[3] == '1') $mode += 01; 
    if ($permissions[3] == '2') $mode += 02; 
    if ($permissions[3] == '3') $mode += 03; 
    if ($permissions[3] == '4') $mode += 04; 
    if ($permissions[3] == '5') $mode += 05; 
    if ($permissions[3] == '6') $mode += 06; 
    if ($permissions[3] == '7') $mode += 07; 

    return($mode);
}
$a = "0777";
chmod("myFolder/", permtooct($a));
```

Answer (score 1):

I needed to feed the mode component of `chmod()` as a variable inside a function.  I spent sufficient time trying (and failing) to convert the string into an octal while maintaining the 0777 value.  In the end, I decided to abandon `chmod()`/`ftp_chmod()` and opted for `ftp_site()` which doesn't choke on string-type mode codes.

```
if(!ftp_site($connection,"chmod {$mode} {$path}/{$file}")){
    // handle the error
}
```

This worked for me.  If this is somehow flawed or not best practice, please explain.

Edit: Some readers may reject this ftp_ solution as cheating because it is not a filesystem function solution.  It was a non-issue for me because I was writing a function in a ftp class.

Answer (score -1):

Octal is not a type. Integer is the type.

You want to convert a string to an int, and because of that the string starts with a zero, it will be an octal integer.

Use [intval](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php) for this:

```
chmod('myFolder/', intval($perm));
```

Comment: This will not work, because this string would get converted to `int(777)` and the leading zero would be gone!

Comment: Read the documentation, I specially added the link... "if string starts with "0", the base is taken as 8 (octal);"

Comment: I will just give you the script: `echo $perm = intval("0777");
 chmod("test/", $perm);
 echo   "<br />" . substr(sprintf('%o', fileperms('test/')), -4);` Create a test folder and test it! See if it outputs 0777 as permission!

Comment: Yep, that script outputs 777<br />0777.

Comment: I just tried this but didn't change the permission to 0777

Comment: @Xelakz That's the proof that this answer is false!

Comment: Is there another way for it? @Rizier123

Comment: @Xelakz Yes you can use `decoct()` like in my answer or like in the answer from @sectus both variants there works also. So you have 3 to choose from

Comment: @Rizier123, sorry... decoct does not work properly in this case.