# php mkdir pass perrmissions from string

Tags: php, mkdir, octal

I am using `mkdir()` to assign directory permissions. But I can not pass file permissions by hard coding them. Instead, I am taking the file permissions from a config file and the value returned by the function that read that file is in string format. I know that If pass 0755 as a string it will not be considered as an octal number.

So I am doing it like

```
mkdir($dirPath, (int)base_convert(env("FILE_ACCESS", "0766"), 8, 10), true);
```

The function env returns the value stored in the config file. However if there are no permissions defined in the config file it simply returns the string `"0766"`.

But the permissions that are being set on the directory are 0744.

Comment: did you mean to write `getenv` instead of `env`? Or is it a custom function - if so, please share it :)

Comment: In case you are using windows, mode is beeing ignored: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php

Comment: @pilan I am using Ubuntu and you don't need to know the logic of env function. It just always returns a string containing file permissions.

Comment: okay, checked `umask` ?

Comment: I don't wanna use that. client want it without umask

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change '0777' string to 0777 octal LITERALLY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28672096/change-0777-string-to-0777-octal-literally)

Answer (score 1):

```
$originalUmask = umask(0); // sets umask to 0 and return original

// do your mkdir here

umask($originalUmask); // back to safe again ;)
```